# Docker-compose is not building one container

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I have the following **docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2.1'
services:
  files:
    image: busybox
    volumes:
      - ./file/input:/file/input
      - ./file/output:/file/output
   [..]  
  classificatore:
    build: classificatore/.
    volumes:    
      - ./classificatore:/src
    volumes_from: 
      - files
    ports: 
      - 8080:5000      
    command: ["python", "/src/main.py"]
    depends_on: 
      rabbit:
        condition: service_healthy

  mpeg-pre-encoder:
    build: mpeg-pre-encoder/.
    volumes:
      - ./mpeg-pre-encoder:/src
      - ./gabac_encoder:/src/gabac_encoder
    volumes_from: 
      - files    
    depends_on: 
      rabbit:
        condition: service_healthy

  rabbit:
    image: rabbitmq
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "rabbitmqctl", "cluster_status"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 2s
      retries: 20
```

and the following **dir structure**:

```
classificatore/
   Dockerfile
   [..]
aggregatore/
   Dockerfile
   [..]
mpeg-pre-encoder/
   Dockerfile
   [..]
docker-compose.yml
[..]
```

the mpeg-pre-encoder **Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3
RUN mkdir /src
ADD requirements.txt /src/.
WORKDIR /src
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /src/.
CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

When I run
docker-compose up -d --build

and check for running containers

```
docker ps -a
```

I get

```
b6d7bac3e9b1        encoder_mpeg-pre-encoder   "python main.py"         13 seconds ago      Exited (1) 9 seconds ago                                                            encoder_mpeg-pre-encoder_1
b1182f765113        encoder_classificatore     "python /src/main.py"    32 minutes ago      Up 32 minutes               0.0.0.0:8080->5000/tcp                                  encoder_classificatore_1
e9d8387430f2        encoder_aggregatore        "python /src/main.py"    32 minutes ago      Up 32 minutes               0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp                                  encoder_aggregatore_1
a69183f42ab6        grafana/grafana:5.1.0      "/run.sh"                About an hour ago   Up About an hour            0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp                                  encoder_grafana_1
ade83e898a98        prom/prometheus            "/bin/prometheus --c…"   About an hour ago   Up 33 minutes               0.0.0.0:9090->9090/tcp                                  encoder_prometheus_1
ff9960a7e924        busybox                    "sh"                     About an hour ago   Exited (0) 12 seconds ago                                                           encoder_files_1
1738eea0645d        rabbitmq                   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 weeks ago         Up 2 hours (healthy)        4369/tcp, 5671/tcp, 25672/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5672->5672/tcp   encoder_rabbit_1
(
```

The encoder_mpeg-pre-encoder container fails during building process.

Any hints on why I get this error?

**EDIT 1**: $docker logs b6d7bac3e9b1

```
2019-06-10 09:25:58,560 In attesa di nuovi job....
2019-06-10 09:25:58,560 RECEIVED: b"{'file_id': '59f311da-f02f-496a-a899-b1afd1768d64', 'parameter_set': {'reads_len': 136, 'myRnameDict': {'chrM': 0}}, 'au': {'id': 0, 'parameter_set_id': 16, 'au_type': 3, 'sequence_id': 0, 'file_name': '/file/output/minisam/59f311da-f02f-496a-a899-b1afd1768d64/CLASS_M chrM 1:7762.sam', 'AU_start_position': 0, 'AU_end_position': 7897}, 'au_count': 1}"
2019-06-10 09:25:58,561 reading the mini sam file
2019-06-10 09:25:58,582 Tempo totale impiegato per la lettura: 0 sec
2019-06-10 09:25:58,582 Tempo totale impiegato per la lettura: 0 sec
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 68, in <module>
    rabbit.wait_for_job(decoded_symbols_from_sam_file)
  File "/src/my_util.py", line 55, in wait_for_job
    self.channel_input.start_consuming()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 1822, in start_consuming
    self.connection.process_data_events(time_limit=None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 758, in process_data_events
    self._dispatch_channel_events()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 521, in _dispatch_channel_events
    impl_channel._get_cookie()._dispatch_events()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 1445, in _dispatch_events
    evt.body)
  File "/src/my_util.py", line 48, in callback
    worker_function(eval(body))
  File "<decorator-gen-1>", line 2, in decoded_symbols_from_sam_file
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/prometheus_client/context_managers.py", line 66, in wrapped
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 38, in decoded_symbols_from_sam_file
    mpegg_fields = convert_sam_to_mpegg(sam_fields, job_data['parameter_set']['myRnameDict'])
  File "/src/mpegg_fields.py", line 40, in convert_sam_to_mpegg
    mpegg_line[MPEGG_FIELD_ECIGAR_STRING] = calculate_ECIGAR_STRING(sam_line)
  File "/src/mpegg_fields.py", line 107, in calculate_ECIGAR_STRING
    raise ('Impossible to calculate ecigar string')
TypeError: exceptions must derive from BaseException
```

**EDIT 2**: running mpeg-pre-encoder script outside Docker

```
$python main.py
2019-06-10 12:49:29,541 Address resolution failed: gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known')
2019-06-10 12:49:29,542 getaddrinfo failed: gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known').
2019-06-10 12:49:29,542 AMQP connection workflow failed: AMQPConnectionWorkflowFailed: 1 exceptions in all; last exception - gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known'); first exception - None.
2019-06-10 12:49:29,543 AMQPConnectionWorkflow - reporting failure: AMQPConnectionWorkflowFailed: 1 exceptions in all; last exception - gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known'); first exception - None
2019-06-10 12:49:29,543 Connection workflow failed: AMQPConnectionWorkflowFailed: 1 exceptions in all; last exception - gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known'); first exception - None
2019-06-10 12:49:29,543 Error in _create_connection().
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/martina/PycharmProjects/mpegg_std/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 451, in _create_connection
    raise self._reap_last_connection_workflow_error(error)
  File "/home/martina/PycharmProjects/mpegg_std/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pika/adapters/utils/selector_ioloop_adapter.py", line 564, in _resolve
    self._flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 745, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 18, in <module>
    rabbit = Rabbit()
  File "/home/martina/PycharmProjects/mpegg_std/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/singleton_decorator/decorator.py", line 14, in __call__
    self._instance = self.__wrapped__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/martina/PycharmProjects/mpegg_std/applicazione/encoder/mpeg-pre-encoder/my_util.py", line 26, in __init__
    self.initConnect()
  File "/home/martina/PycharmProjects/mpegg_std/applicazione/encoder/mpeg-pre-encoder/my_util.py", line 19, in initConnect
    self.connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host=RABBIT_HOST))
  File "/home/martina/PycharmProjects/mpegg_std/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 360, in __init__
    self._impl = self._create_connection(parameters, _impl_class)
  File "/home/martina/PycharmProjects/mpegg_std/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 451, in _create_connection
    raise self._reap_last_connection_workflow_error(error)
  File "/home/martina/PycharmProjects/mpegg_std/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pika/adapters/utils/selector_ioloop_adapter.py", line 564, in _resolve
    self._flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 745, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

**EDIT 3:** 
I isolated the error coming from the exception, but I get a more serious error. In fact the mpeg-pre-encoder service is fired when the classificatore service sends data to a queue. I think something is broken in rabbitMQ, how can I check if I'm right?

Below the mpeg-pre-encoder service building log:

```
Building mpeg-pre-encoder
Step 1/7 : FROM python:3
 ---> a4cc999cf2aa
Step 2/7 : RUN mkdir /src
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 31d8a2dc751d
Step 3/7 : ADD requirements.txt /src/.
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9c58880cc0b1
Step 4/7 : WORKDIR /src
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 910b4249cc31
Step 5/7 : RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a8dc0f729257
Step 6/7 : ADD . /src/.
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 591968ce0427
Step 7/7 : CMD ["python", "main.py"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b1500f95a936
Successfully built b1500f95a936
Successfully tagged encoder_mpeg-pre-encoder:latest
```

It seems building fine but as soon as I run `docker ps -a`

```
9e7c4723cd98        encoder_mpeg-pre-encoder   "python main.py"         17 seconds ago      Exited (1) 14 seconds ago                                                            encoder_mpeg-pre-encoder_1
```

with a different error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 45, in <module>
    rabbit.wait_for_job(decoded_symbols_from_sam_file)
  File "/src/my_util.py", line 55, in wait_for_job
    self.channel_input.start_consuming()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 1822, in start_consuming
    self.connection.process_data_events(time_limit=None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 758, in process_data_events
    self._dispatch_channel_events()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 521, in _dispatch_channel_events
    impl_channel._get_cookie()._dispatch_events()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 1445, in _dispatch_events
    evt.body)
  File "/src/my_util.py", line 48, in callback
    worker_function(eval(body))
  File "<decorator-gen-1>", line 2, in decoded_symbols_from_sam_file
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/prometheus_client/context_managers.py", line 66, in wrapped
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 26, in decoded_symbols_from_sam_file
    COUNTER_INPUT_FILE_SIZE.inc(path.getsize(file_path))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/genericpath.py", line 50, in getsize
    return os.stat(filename).st_size
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/file/output/minisam/9fdb727a-5093-4800-a1ba-c807dc48ca99/CLASS_P chrM 1:7757.sam'
```

Comment: whats output of `docker logs b6d7bac3e9b1`?

Comment: I add what you asked. I'm working to solve the exception.. Since I'm pretty new to Docker could you tell me why in the mpeg-pre-encoder/ dir I do not have the dir .vscode/ while I've it in the other two containers?

Comment: It looks like the image is building fine (though you're hiding all of it with bind-mounted volumes) but is crashing on startup.  Both the incorrect `raise` statement and the logic that leads there look specific to your application.  Can you run the same script, with the same RabbitMQ input message, outside of Docker?

Comment: Hope I've got what you asked, check edit 2. Thanks

Comment: @user123892 well, this couldn’t be solved without sources and a debugging session. One obvious thing: filenames can’t include “:” on linux, and the one in the stack trace does.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to run python 2 code with python 3 interpreter. They changed how the exceptions are handled between the versions, so now you can’t just `raise 'My exception'`.

Change the base container to python 2 or rewrite the code, python 2 is nearing the end of life in 2020.

Comment: I"m working on a Ubuntu VM. I changed the mpeg-pre-encoder Dockerfile FROM python:3 to FROM python:2 but no luck. I still get the same error. The python --version of the main project is "Python 3.6.7". 
My local machine runs macOS and the same project throws no error with Python 3.7.0

Comment: @user123892 I've looked into it, and string exceptions are not supported since python 2.5 or 2.6. As for your machine not throwing errors, I think this line simply isn't executed. It feels like an error in source code though (somebody missed the exception name before string), I doubt you're working with an ancient project.

Comment: I added an EDIT 3. I'm just wondering if I should post a new question